# Python inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm having some problems with inheritance. I need to import simplejson or install if it can't be found and import. I'm doing this in a another class and sending it via inheritance where needed. The way I'm doing it here works in python 2.6+ but not in 2.4.

```
# This class will hold all things needed over in all classes

import subprocess

class Global(object):

   def __init__(self):
       # Making sure simple json is installed and accessible
       try:
           import simplejson as json
           self.json = json
       except ImportError:
           subprocess.Popen(['apt-get -y install python-simplejson'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).wait()
           import simplejson as json
           self.json = json
```

And I'm passing it to this class

```
class Init(Global):

   # Holds json object
   INFO_OBJECT = {
       'filesystem': {
           'root': {},
           'archive': {},
           'buffer': {}
       },
       'mysql': {
           'is_corrupt': False,
           'corrupt_files': {},
           'version': ''
       }
   }

   def __init__(self):
       super(Init, self).__init__()
       self.create_log_folder()
       self.create_object()
       self.gather_info()

   # if json object not found in file create a empty on and save it
   def create_object(self):
       try:
           f = open('/usr/local/careview/video/archive/rcpchecker/info/info.txt')
           info_object = self.json.load(f)
           f.close()
           self.INFO_OBJECT = info_object
       except self.json.JSONDecodeError:
           f = open('/usr/local/careview/video/archive/rcpchecker/info/info.txt', 'wb')
           self.json.dump(self.INFO_OBJECT, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
           f.close()
```

This is my Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Main.py", line 42, in ?
  start()
File "Main.py", line 11, in start
  Init()
File "/home/careview/ibarron/rcptester/Init/init.py", line 29, in __init__
  self.create_object()
File "/home/careview/ibarron/rcptester/Init/init.py", line 43, in create_object
  except self.json.JSONDecodeError:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONDecodeError'
```

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(['apt-get -y install python-simplejson'], …` – just no.

Comment: @poke he forgot "sudo"

Comment: I run python as root

Comment: I believe the original comment was implying that it is a better practice to install your dependencies before you run your software rather than trying to install your dependencies inside your software.

Comment: How exactly is this not working in Python 2.4?  What error are you getting?

Comment: Your code is not well formatted. The class methods are not indented properly. You should edit your question and fix that.

Comment: I would prefer it be that way too. I have it for testing purposes. My problem is inheritance not that.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: How is your problem inheritance? Why has this question suddenly changed so drastically? What, exactly, about this code does not work?

Comment: What is up with everyone and indentions. It pasted in weird.

Comment: Why is the import inside the  `Global.__init__` method?

Comment: If i were to try to import it outside of the class it would crash with ImportError

Comment: Why are you assigning an imported module to a member? That's not how imports work in python.

Comment: @IsaacBarron: Yeah. The stackoverflow editor can be a pain when it comes to indentation.

Comment: @b4hand Im new to python. I've seen it seen it done in a tutorial. I haven't been doing this but in this case I need a solution to check if the import worked before it crashed the program.

Comment: @IsaacBarron: You can have a `try` block at the top-level just like you can inside of a class.

Comment: @HåkenLid: it usually is an indication the original code mixes tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not the question, but you should not be using subprocess.popen for this. Use pip. It's great.

```
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import pip
    try:
        import os
        isAdmin = os.getuid() == 0
    except AttributeError:
        import ctypes
        isAdmin = ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() != 0
    if isAdmin:
        c = pip.main(['install', 'simplejson'])
    else:
        c = pip.main(['install', '--user', 'simplejson'])
    if c:
        print("Could not install 'simplejson'.")
        exit(c) # => or desired error code... don't use 0 (thanks to Håken Lid for pointing this out) because it indicates success
    import simplejson as json
self.json = json
```

As for your error, open python2.4 interpreter and just simply run:

```
>>> import simplejson as json
>>> 'JSONDecodeError' in dir(json)
True # => or false?
```

If it does not exist (perhaps the 2.4 version does not support it?), you can easily grab the source code from the 2.7 module:

```
>>> from inspect import getsourcelines as gsl
>>> import simplejson as json
>>> json.JSONDecodeError
<class 'simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError'>
>>> x, _ = gsl(json.scanner.JSONDecodeError)
>>> print(''.join(x))
class JSONDecodeError(ValueError):
    """Subclass of ValueError with the following additional properties:

    msg: The unformatted error message
    doc: The JSON document being parsed
    pos: The start index of doc where parsing failed
    end: The end index of doc where parsing failed (may be None)
    lineno: The line corresponding to pos
    colno: The column corresponding to pos
    endlineno: The line corresponding to end (may be None)
    endcolno: The column corresponding to end (may be None)

    """
    # Note that this exception is used from _speedups
    def __init__(self, msg, doc, pos, end=None):
        ValueError.__init__(self, errmsg(msg, doc, pos, end=end))
        self.msg = msg
        self.doc = doc
        self.pos = pos
        self.end = end
        self.lineno, self.colno = linecol(doc, pos)
        if end is not None:
            self.endlineno, self.endcolno = linecol(doc, end)
        else:
            self.endlineno, self.endcolno = None, None

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (self.msg, self.doc, self.pos, self.end)
```

Now, in the python2.4 error, you can easily check if it has the attribute. If not, add it.

```
if not hasattr('json.scanner', 'JSONDecodeError'):

    class myJSONDecodeError(ValueError):
        """Subclass of ValueError with the following additional properties:

        msg: The unformatted error message
        doc: The JSON document being parsed
        pos: The start index of doc where parsing failed
        end: The end index of doc where parsing failed (may be None)
        lineno: The line corresponding to pos
        colno: The column corresponding to pos
        endlineno: The line corresponding to end (may be None)
        endcolno: The column corresponding to end (may be None)

        """
        # Note that this exception is used from _speedups
        def __init__(self, msg, doc, pos, end=None):
            ValueError.__init__(self, errmsg(msg, doc, pos, end=end))
            self.msg = msg
            self.doc = doc
            self.pos = pos
            self.end = end
            self.lineno, self.colno = linecol(doc, pos)
            if end is not None:
                self.endlineno, self.endcolno = linecol(doc, end)
            else:
                self.endlineno, self.endcolno = None, None

        def __reduce__(self):
            return self.__class__, (self.msg, self.doc, self.pos, self.end)

        self.json.JSONDecodeError = self.json.scanner.JSONDecodeError = myJSONDecodeError
```

Comment: That's a good answer. But `exit(0)` indicates success, so it's better to exit with a different exit code or to raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will keep this for future reference. But I just tried importing pip its not installed either. Im not working on just one machine. we have over 8,000 in the field and until I have this program working we aren't going to install these packages. I could take that part out. install the package my self then run the code. I was just trying to automate for testing

Comment: @Goodies Thank you. You were right 2.4 simplejson did not support JSONDecodeError adding it fixed my problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get install` won't guarantee that you are installing `simplejson` for all versions of python. It will only work for the *system installed* version of Python which may or may not be 2.4. That's going to depend highly on what underlying version of Linux or Ubuntu or Debian you are using. If you want to be portable across multiple Python versions, you should be using Python's method of managing dependencies instead of trying to do it via `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a ton to say about what's going on here, but I think the other comments have that covered.

It looks like `simplejson` simply isn't supported in python versions below 2.5: https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson.  And I'm sure if you're using apt-get, you're installing the latest.  Try just using python 2.4's normal json package (if there is one - I would assume there is).

Comment: This is not my problem. it works fine on python 2.4 and above
                                            

`Python 2.4.4 (#2, Jan 24 2010, 11:19:18) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import simplejson
>>>`

Comment: There's a big difference between your code loading and running and your code executing correctly.